# Shortest paths from a single source (Dijkstra and Bellman-Ford)

Tags: python, graph, pathfinding

I did not implement a priority queue in Dijkstra. I'm not sure if a trivial priority queue is the best choice, since, after each iteration, several elements change their value. Maybe it is better to just "bubble" modified elements to their new places.

Tests are implemented very roughly, but it is not the point here.

```
import random

class WeightedGraph:
    # constructor randomley generates a graph, 
    # given the number of vertice, min and max number of vertice from each vertex
    def __init__(self, number_vertice, 
                 min_edges_per_vertice, 
                 max_edges_per_vertice, 
                 negative_weights_allowed = False):
        assert number_vertice > 0
        assert min_edges_per_vertice >= 0
        assert max_edges_per_vertice < number_vertice 
        assert min_edges_per_vertice <= max_edges_per_vertice 

        self.edges_per_vertice = [[] for _ in xrange(number_vertice)]
        for vertex_from in xrange(number_vertice):
            number_of_edges = random.randint(min_edges_per_vertice, max_edges_per_vertice)
            # to make sure there are no self loops, 
            # sample ends < counter and ends > counter separately
            qty_edges_before = int(round(number_of_edges * vertex_from / number_vertice))
            if qty_edges_before > number_of_edges:
                qty_edges_before = number_of_edges 
            if qty_edges_before >= vertex_from:
                qty_edges_before = vertex_from
            if (number_of_edges-qty_edges_before) >= (number_vertice - vertex_from - 1):
                qty_edges_before = number_of_edges + vertex_from - number_vertice + 1

            vertice_to = []
            if qty_edges_before > 0:
                vertice_to += random.sample(xrange(vertex_from), qty_edges_before) 
            if qty_edges_before < number_of_edges:
                vertice_to += random.sample(xrange(vertex_from+1, number_vertice), number_of_edges-qty_edges_before)

            if negative_weights_allowed:
                self.edges_per_vertice[vertex_from] = [(v, 2*random.random()-1) for v in vertice_to]                
            else:
                self.edges_per_vertice[vertex_from] = [(v, random.random()) for v in vertice_to]
            self.edges_per_vertice[vertex_from].sort(key = lambda x:x[0]) 

    def Print(self):
        vertex = -1
        for epv in self.edges_per_vertice: # iterate over ends of the edge
            vertex += 1
            for other_vertice, weight in epv:
                print "edge (", vertex, ", ", other_vertice, "), weight = ", weight

    def BellmanFordPathToSrource(self, single_source):
        assert single_source >= 0
        assert single_source < len(self.edges_per_vertice)

        # first element of a tuple is the distance, the second one is the ancestor
        result = [(None, None) for _ in self.edges_per_vertice]
        result[single_source] = (0, None) # distance to itself is 0
        negative_loop_edge = None
        for iteration in range(len(self.edges_per_vertice)): # iterate over lengths of paths, last loop for checking
            for vertex_from in range(len(self.edges_per_vertice)): # iterate over beginning of the edge
                for vertex_to, weight in self.edges_per_vertice[vertex_from]:
                    if result[vertex_to][0] == None: # we differentiate between 0 and None
                        continue # we cannot relax the edge that comes from unreachable vertice
                    new_distance = result[vertex_to][0] + weight
                    if (result[vertex_from][0] == None) or (result[vertex_from][0] > new_distance):
                        if iteration == len(self.edges_per_vertice) - 1:
                            negative_loop_edge = (vertex_from, vertex_to)
                        else:
                            result[vertex_from] = (new_distance, vertex_to)               

        for vertex in xrange(len(result)):
            print "vertex ", vertex, ", distance ", result[vertex][0], ", ancestor ", result[vertex][1]            
        if negative_loop_edge:
            print "negative_loop_edge: ", negative_loop_edge[0], ", ", negative_loop_edge[1]            
        return result, negative_loop_edge

    def BellmanFordPathFromSource(self, single_source):
        if not self.edges_per_vertice:
            return
        assert single_source >= 0
        assert single_source < len(self.edges_per_vertice)

        # first element of a tuple is the distance, the second one is the ancestor
        result = [(None, None) for _ in self.edges_per_vertice]
        result[single_source] = (0, None) # distance to itself is 0
        for _ in self.edges_per_vertice: # iterate over lengths of paths, last loop for checking
            relaxed_edge = None
            for vertex_from in range(len(self.edges_per_vertice)): # iterate over the beginnings of the edge
                relaxed_edge_this_vertex = self.__RelaxEdgesFromSource(result = result, vertex_from = vertex_from)
                if not relaxed_edge:
                    relaxed_edge = relaxed_edge_this_vertex
            if not relaxed_edge:
                break #stop if during the iteration no edge was relaxed

        negative_loop_edge = relaxed_edge   
        for vertex in xrange(len(result)):
            print "vertex ", vertex, ", distance ", result[vertex][0], ", ancestor ", result[vertex][1]            
        if negative_loop_edge:
            print "negative_loop_edge: ", negative_loop_edge[0], ", ", negative_loop_edge[1]            
        return result, negative_loop_edge  

    def __RelaxEdgesFromSource(self, result, vertex_from): #direction from source outwards
        if result[vertex_from][0] == None: # we differentiate between 0 and None
            return None # we cannot relax the edge that comes from unreachable vertice
        relaxed_edge = None
        for vertex_to, weight in self.edges_per_vertice[vertex_from]:
            new_distance = result[vertex_from][0] + weight
            if (result[vertex_to][0] == None) or (result[vertex_to][0] > new_distance):
                result[vertex_to] = (new_distance, vertex_from)
                relaxed_edge = (vertex_from, vertex_to) # this edge has been relaxed
        return relaxed_edge # we return **any** relaxed edge, provided at least one edge was relaxed

    def DijkstraFromSource(self, single_source):
        assert single_source >= 0
        assert single_source < len(self.edges_per_vertice)

        visited_vertice = set()
        queueing_vertice = {v for v in range(len(self.edges_per_vertice))} 
        result = [(None, None) for _ in range(len(self.edges_per_vertice))]#(distance, ancestor)
        result[single_source] = (0, None) # distance to itself is 0

        current_vertex = single_source        
        while current_vertex != None: #differentiate between 0 and None

            #relax all edges from current_vertex
            queueing_vertice.remove(current_vertex)
            visited_vertice.add(current_vertex)
            self.__RelaxEdgesFromSource(result = result, vertex_from = current_vertex)

            # find next current vertex
            current_vertex_candidate = None
            min_distance_so_far = None
            for vertex in queueing_vertice:
                if (result[vertex][0] == None):
                    continue
                if (min_distance_so_far != None): 
                    if min_distance_so_far <= result[vertex][0]:
                        continue 
                current_vertex_candidate = vertex
                min_distance_so_far = result[vertex][0]
            current_vertex = current_vertex_candidate                    

        for vertex in xrange(len(result)):
            print "vertex ", vertex, ", distance ", result[vertex][0], ", ancestor ", result[vertex][1]
        return result            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    random.seed(10000)
    wg = WeightedGraph(5, 0, 0)
    wg.Print()
    wg.BellmanFordPathFromSource(single_source = 0); wg.DijkstraFromSource(single_source = 0);
    wg = WeightedGraph(5, 4, 4)
    wg.Print()
    wg.BellmanFordPathFromSource(single_source = 0); wg.DijkstraFromSource(single_source = 0);
    wg = WeightedGraph(5, 2, 3)
    wg.Print()
    wg.BellmanFordPathFromSource(single_source = 0); wg.DijkstraFromSource(single_source = 0);
    wg = WeightedGraph(5, 1, 1, True)
    wg.Print()
    wg.BellmanFordPathFromSource(single_source = 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Follow the pep8 style guide
2. The `self.edges_per_vertice` initialization should be moved into its own function.
3. Many parts can be greatly simplified by optimized by using `numpy` with vectorized operations.
4. In `Print` (which shouldn't be called that, btw), you can use `enumerate` rather than keeping track of the vertex number manually.
5. You can do `x <= y < z`.
6. You should probably use single leading `_`, since your code doesn't benefit from name mangling.
7. You can reverse `if (result[vertex_from][0] == None) or (result[vertex_from][0] > new_distance):` and use a `continue` to reduce the nesting by one level.
8. You can use string replacement, for example `print 'vertex {}, distance {}, ancestor {}'.format(vertex, *result[vertex])`.
9. In `BellmanFordPathToSrource`, at the end define the string outside the loop with `printstr = 'vertex {}, distance {}, ancestor {}'` and then on each cycle of the loop replace it with `print prinstr.format(vertex, *result[vertex])`.
10. In `BellmanFordPathToSrource`, in the final loop you can use `for vetex, vresult in enumerate(result)` to avoid having to index into `result`.
11. In `DijkstraFromSource`, you can do `set(range(x))` instead of using a set comprehension.
12. You can do `[(x, y)]*z` to make list of tuples.  Do **not** do `[[x, y]]*z`, though.
13. You should use `is None` or `is not None` instead of `== None` or `!= None`.
14. You don't need to wrap single `if` tests in `( )`.
15. You should make a `main` function and put all the code in `if __name__ == '__main__':` in there.  Then just call that function in `if __name__ == '__main__':`.